# How would I implement a function to extract the elements of this class?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, generic-programming

I was messing around with implementing tuples in C++ for fun and I got stuck with how I would, given the class below modify it so that I can easily by using templates extract each element by only using an index. Similar to std::get.

**TL;DR**: How would an implementation for extracting the elements inside the tuple look like?

```
template<typename first_t, typename ... arg_v>
class Tuple : public Tuple<arg_v ...>
{
public:

    Tuple()
    {
    }

    Tuple(const first_t&& A) :
        element(A)
    {
    }

    Tuple(const first_t& A, arg_v& ... args) :
        element(A), Tuple<arg_v ...>::Tuple(args ...)
    {
    }

    Tuple(const first_t&& A, arg_v&& ... args) :
        element(A), Tuple<arg_v ...>::Tuple(args ...)
    {
    }

    first_t element;
};

template<typename last_t>
class Tuple<last_t>
{
public:
    Tuple()
    {
    }

    Tuple(const last_t& A) :
        element(A)
    {
    }

    Tuple(const last_t&& A) :
        element(A)
    {
    }
    last_t element;
};
```

Comment: you can look at the source code of boost::tuple or std::tuple for guidance.

Comment: Your move constructors are incorrect - `const&&` isn't something you can move from, and then you aren't moving from anything anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a recursive method.
I know that pointers to `void` are evil, but we don't know which type will be returned, only who is using the code knows it; the cast to the type we want will be performed only by the last `get`.

Keep in mind that this code will cast `void*`to what you want without any check.

```
class Tuple : public Tuple<arg_v ...>
{
    template<typename T>
    void get(int index, T& out)
    {
        out = *static_cast<T*>(get(index));
    }

    void* get(unsigned int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
            return &element;
        else
            return Tuple<arg_v ...>::get(index - 1);
    }
};
class Tuple<last_t>
{
    void* get(unsigned int)
    {
        return &element;
    }
};
```

Comment: `static_cast<Tuple<arg_v ...>>` makes a copy

Comment: I changed it, now it accesses the base class without cast. Thank you.